# How to find sim card availability in UWP windows phone

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am developing a UWP app, in which I want check for sim availability.

If sim is available I need activate phone call , else i will activate skype call.

I am trying different api's to get sim availability, but nothing gives exact result.

Can anyone help to get sim availability?

Thanks in advance.
Noorul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is similar topic: [Whether SIM card is available or not in windows phone universal project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177243/whether-sim-card-is-available-or-not-in-windows-phone-universal-project)

The code from should work also in Windows 10 because [ChatMessageManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat.chatmessagemanager) class is available also in UWP

```
bool simAvailable = false;
var device = await ChatMessageManager.GetTransportsAsync();
if (device != null && device.Count > 0)
{
foreach (var item in device)
 {
    if (item.TransportFriendlyName != "No SIM")
    {
        simAvailable = true;
        break;
    }
 }
}
```

PS: Don't forget to add chat message access capability in your application manifest
PPS: If you phone language is not English you will get "No SIM" message on you language (thankfully to @user1195883 comments)

Comment: I think this will not work if the language of the phone is not EN.

Comment: @user1195883,  you mean that TransportFriendlyName would be translated to the phone language?

Comment: Exactly, I have my phone set to German and I got "Keine SIM Karte"